# Work in Germany without registration

Tags: germany, spain, health-insurance

I have a couple of questions regarding the registration process in Germany and the Insurance.

I have been working in Germany for the last 10 years, I would like to come back to Spain and work remotely from there.

Can I do the de-registration (Abmeldung) and still work for my company?
Can I do the de-registration and give it later to the insurance company (Krankenkasse), whenever I found a job in Spain or a way to work permanently in Spain for my current company (Freelancer for example).
What would happen if I do the de-registration in the Krankenkasse?
How long can I work in Spain without paying taxes in Spain?

As extra info: I already lived in Germany for more than 183 days this year, so I have to pay the taxes in Germany as far as I know.
My company doesn't have an office in Spain.

Comment: To many questions with mixed topics. 1) When you move to Spain, giving up you place of residence, you must deregister that residence. **Everything else** is based on any Spanish/German double tax agreements which regulates where taxes and social insurance must be paid. Seeking advice from a Steuerberater, that specializes in Spain is the best thing for you (or your Employer) to do.

Comment: This page suggests that once you take up residence in Spain and work from there, Spanish taxes and social security must be paid. It also states that a Steuerberater can deal with this on behalf of an Employer that has no representation in Spain. [Wenn das Homeoffice mit ins Ausland zieht – Personalwirtschaft.de](https://www.personalwirtschaft.de/hr-organisation/auslandsentsendung/artikel/wenn-das-homeoffice-mit-ins-ausland-zieht.html)